# Debugger opens an unknown 'SOURCE' file

Tags: javascript, debugging, javascript-debugger

I'm trying to debug a small program in javascript, when I open the debugger section in the console, I set a breakpoint, and refresh the page to start debugging, until now everything is working just fine, but the moment I click on one of these buttons (step out, in,over) a new file named 'SOURCE' gets opened and it contains this following line

```
window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__ && window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__.renderers.size > 0
```

this is the first one:
[image]

and when i click on one of them again, another file with the same name 'SOURCE' gets opens
this is the second file:
[image]

this has something to do with the react dev tools, but i dont know what it is, because im debgging a simple javascript program that doesn't use react,thing were working fine before.
this is the javascript program.
[image]